# Python: Parse CSV by combining all values for a key into 1 row and store a new dataframe

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I have a csv file that contains a key-value pair and I am being asked to combine all the values associated with the same key into one row 
For example:

```
Key,Col1,Col2,Col3
A, 1, A1, C9
A  2, C9, C1
A, 5, C1, C4
B, 7, A8, C5
D, 10 A2, C3
```

**UPDATED the results since there was a mistake on the first row**\

This should result to the following: RECORDS for the dataframe
   key value

```
Key,NewCol
A,A1:1:C9:C9:2:C1:C1:5:C4
B,A8:7:C5
D,A2:10:C3
```

As you can see, I needed them in an order of continuity by Key 
For the records with Key = A : the series should be in the order of : 
Col2-Col3    value A1 -- C9 
**Then next record should be have Col2-Col3 value of C9 -- XX
The records are not always in the right row-sequence so i need to make sure that this is accomplished as I store the record**

i started doing this and reading the csv and checking each read with a corresponding value of key and then adjusting the value of value if there exists a key or not.

```
import csv
df = []
with open('example.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        if df.loc[df.key == row[0]]:
            exist_value  = df[value] 
            df[value]    = exist_value + row[2]+":"+row[1]+":"+row[3]
        else:
            df[key] = row[0]
            df[value] = row[2]+":"+row[1]+":"+row[3]
```

Question:
1. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?  I have a big file to read and I have to do more processing to it like:

Comment: Are you meant to be using a pandas DataFrame here? Your `df` is a Python list...

Comment: Can you explain the logic in more details?

Comment: are the commas denoting different columns? in the dummy data given above?

Comment: See the updated data inputs: I added headers to make it wasier to understand but the comma is a delimiter for each of the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('waka.csv', header=None)
result = df.groupby(0).agg(lambda x: ':'.join(x.apply(str))).apply(lambda x: ':'.join(x), axis=1)
result
```

[image]

How it works:

- `import pandas as pd` import pandas library
- `df = pd.read_csv('waka.csv', header=None)` read csv file and write it into the dataframe
- `df.groupby(0)` [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) by the column **0** (you have no headers so you have to use column indices
- `agg(lambda x: ':'.join(x.apply(str)))` join all rows in every grouped block
- `apply(lambda x: ':'.join(x), axis=1)` join all columns in the new all-containing row to the one all-containing cell

Result is the [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) object with indices equal to grouped elements.

---

**Edit 1:** Update for a question specification.

I didn't find any simple solutions for joining grouped rows first. I can recommend only this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('waka.csv', header=None)
grouped = df.groupby(0)
headers = []
bodies = []
for group in grouped.groups:
    headers.append(group)
    bodies.append(grouped.get_group(group).drop(columns=0).apply(lambda x: ':'.join([str(e) if type(e) != str else e for e in x]), axis=1).str.cat(sep=':'))
pd.Series(bodies, index=headers)
```

It is the same mostly, but the main line with `bodies` generation is a bit different:

- `grouped` grouped df
- `.get_group(group)` particular group
- `.drop(columns=0)` remove column with grouped index (A, B or D)
- `.apply(lambda x: ':'.join(WAKA), axis=1)` join rows into strings
- `WAKA = [str(e) if type(e) != str else e for e in x]` handle non-str elements
- `.str.cat(sep=':')` concatenate rows into one string

Will return:

```
B                    7:A8:C5
D                   10:A2:C3
A    1:A1:C9:2:C9:C1:5:C1:C4
dtype: object
```

Comment: Your result is not completely correct. the columns in the original row are a set and needs to be incorporated as a set of values in the order that is stated. Would there be a way to manipulate the panda function to do this? See updated output.

Comment: @vumux is there a way to keep the set of columsn after the key as a set instead of joining them by axis..

Comment: Updated my solution.

Comment: @vumux, is there a way to make the outputs for the lambda be stored into individual columns instead of having 1 long string?